plantuml map elements layout fix
Now I have a capability card in plantuml. I have a huge number of elements and in order for the map to be readable, I made connections "obj1" -[hidden]->"obj2" To arrange objects in a hierarchy from top to bottom.
Current code:
@startuml
top to bottom direction
title  Карта
skinparam TitleFontSize 32
!pragma layout elk
rectangle "Managing business" <<$archimate/strategy-capability>> #Strategy {
rectangle "Managing profit" <<$archimate/strategy-capability>> #Strategy
rectangle "Managing expenses" <<$archimate/strategy-capability>> #Strategy
rectangle "Managing company" <<$archimate/strategy-capability>> #Strategy{
rectangle "Marketing" <<$archimate/strategy-capability>> #Strategy
rectangle "Staff" <<$archimate/strategy-capability>> #Strategy
}
}
"Managing company" -[hidden]-> "Managing profit"
"Managing profit" -[hidden]-> "Managing expenses"


@enduml

When using the parameter !pragma layout elk
all the huge number of elements perfectly fits on the map from top to bottom, each under each.
However, archimate capability icons are rendered only for the most nested elements.
When I remove the !pragma layout elk parameter, the archimate icons and block color are applied to all. However, my connections "obj1" -[hidden]-> "obj2" Seem to stop working and the elements begin to be arranged randomly and rather uncomprehendingly.
I would like to know how to make it so that without the !pragma layuot elk indicator, the elements would be positioned as conveniently as if there were this parameter.

ELK support looks like a work in progress: https://github.com/plantuml/plantuml/issues/534 Maybe you can get some help there?
